# Compare 2 delimited files and output differences

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, columns

I have asked similar questions here a couple times in the past with great success, but now my needs have slightly changed and I am struggling to get the exact output I am looking for.

I would like to compare 2 *similar* delimited files, but they will have different number of rows and some duplicates.  The files will have identical headers.

`file1.txt`

```
mem_id     date     time     building
aa1         bb1      cc1     dd1
aa2         bb2      cc2     dd2
aa3         bb3      ccx3    dd3
aa4         bb4      cc4     dd4
aa5         bb5      cc5     dd5
```

`file2.txt`

```
mem_id     date     time     building
aa1         bby1     cc1     ddy1
aa2         bb2      cc2     dd2  
aa3         bb3      cc3     dd3
aa4         bb4      cc4     dd4
aa4         bb4a     cc4a    dd4a
```

You will see there are 4 differences:

1- File2, mem_id aa1 has a “y” in both the "date" and "building" column

2- File1, mem_id aa3 has an “x” in "time" column

3- File1, has a mem_id aa5

4- File2, mem_id aa4 has 2 entries

I would like to run a script to output only the differences between the 2 files (skipping identical lines).  Everything I have tried gets hung-up on the duplicate or skipped lines, thus messing up output throughout the file.  If all lines match, the following code works well:

`current_code`

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)    header[i] = $i}NR==FNR {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {A[i,NR] = $i} next}{  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (A[i,FNR] != $i) print header[1]"#-"$1": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", A[i,FNR]" / " ARGV[2] " value= "$i}'
```

`desired_output.txt`

```
Mem_id#-aa1 : date-  file1.txt value = bb1 / file2.txt value= bby1
Mem_id#-aa1 : building-  file1.txt value = dd1 / file2.txt value= ddy1
Mem_id#-aa3 : time-  file1.txt value = ccx3 / file2.txt value= dd3
Mem_id#-aa4 : date-  file1.txt value =        / file2.txt value= bb4a
Mem_id#-aa4 : time-  file1.txt value =        / file2.txt value= cc4a
Mem_id#-aa4 : building-  file1.txt value =        / file2.txt value= dd4a
Mem_id#-aa5 : date-  file1.txt value = bb5 / file2.txt value= 
Mem_id#-aa5 : time-  file1.txt value =  cc5 / file2.txt value= 
Mem_id#-aa5 : building-  file1.txt value =  dd5 / file2.txt value=
```

Comment: Can file1 have duplicate `mem_id`s as well? What happens when both files have 2 different entries for the same `mem_id` 2x2 comparisons?

Comment: yes, both might have duplicate `mem_id`s.  When both files have 2 different entries for the same `mem_id` it will begin to "offset" and compare `aa4` with `aa5`

Comment: Is that offset shift what you want, or the description of your `awk` one-liner? (which, becasue of my inexperience, I have difficulty to decipher).

Answer (score 3):

The following python program should do what you want, or something very close to it.

- In the `desired_output.txt` the 3rd line seems to be erroneous:

  ```
  Mem_id#-aa3 : time-  file1.txt value = ccx3 / file2.txt value= dd3
  ```

  the `dd3 should probably be`cc3`

  Apart from that the output from the program matches except for whitespace, which seems a bit irregular in your sample output.
- The input is considered to be ordered by key (memid)
- The program buffers by default 4 rows (max_diff + 1) while trying to sync up. If none from the keys right in that buffer matches the "current" key and vv both are considered non-matching and printed and the next pair is tried. If a key is found, the non-matching items in the other buffer or output first.
- The sample input is a bit restricted on what behaviour is expected when the first and the second line have the same memid twice (or more).

  In `output()` I try to match
  any rows and pop all matching (both from left and right). Therefore the order of matching lines within the same memid is not important. If left or right or both are empty afterwards printing is easy (especially when both are empty). For the rest the I match each remaining line from the left to the right.
- The `fmt` string in `line_out()` determines the output, you can freely change/reorder that.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161913/33055

from __future__ import print_function
from collections import OrderedDict
from logging import debug

import sys


class RowBuffer:
    def __init__(self, file_name, delim=None, max_diff=3):
        """delim is the character that is used for splitting input.
        None->whitespace
        """
        self._verbose = 0
        self._file_name = file_name
        self._fp = open(self._file_name)
        self._delim = delim
        self._max_diff = max_diff
        self._head = self._fp.readline().split(delim)
        # the buffer consists of a maximum of max_diff entries
        # the keys are the first items of a row, the value a list
        # of all other items on that row
        self._buffer = OrderedDict()
        self.fill_buffer()

    def compare(self, rb):
        """check if self._buffer"""
        if self._head != rb._head:
            print('headings differ:\n  {}\n  {}'.format(
                self._head, rb._head))
        while self._buffer:
            l = self.get()
            try:
                r = rb.get()
            except KeyError:
                debug('only left %s', l[0])
                self.output(l, None, rb)
                break
            if l[0] == r[0]:
                debug('compare vals %s', l[0])
                self.output(l, r, rb)
                continue
            if l[0] in rb:
                # left key in right, but not at top
                # output right until top keys are same
                while l[0] != r[0]:
                    debug('only right %s', r[0])
                    self.output(None, r, rb)
                    r = rb.get()
                self.output(l, r, rb)
                continue
            if r[0] in self:
                # right key in left, but not at top
                # output left until top keys are same
                while l[0] != r[0]:
                    debug('only left %s', l[0])
                    self.output(l, None, rb)
                    l = self.get()
                self.output(l, r, rb)
                continue
            # neither found: output both
            debug('neither left in right nor vv %s %s', l[0], r[0])
            self.output(l, None, rb)
            self.output(None, r, rb)
        while rb._buffer:  # remaining in right file
            r = rb.get()
            debug('only right %s', r[0])
            self.output(None, r, rb)

    def output(self, l, r, right):
        fmt1 = '{col0_header}#-{col0_value} : {col_header}-  ' \
            '{left_file_name} value = {left_value} / ' \
            '{right_file_name} value= {right_value}'
        d = dict(
            col0_header=self._head[0],
            left_file_name=self._file_name,
            right_file_name=right._file_name,
        )
        if l is not None and r is not None:
            # one or more values on both sides, compare all lines on the
            # left with all on the right remove any matching pairs
            match = {}  # left index to right index
            for lidx, lv in enumerate(l[1]):
                for ridx, rv in enumerate(r[1]):
                    if lv == rv:
                        if lidx not in match:
                            match[lidx] = ridx
            # pop from back of list, not invalidate index
            for lidx in sorted(match, reverse=True):
                l[1].pop(lidx)
            for ridx in sorted(match.values(), reverse=True):
                r[1].pop(lidx)
        if r is None or not r[1]:
            for lv in l[1]:
                for idx, k in enumerate(self._head[1:]):
                    self.line_out(d, col0_value=l[0], col_header=k,
                                  left_value=lv[idx], right_value='    ')
            return
        if l is None or not l[1]:
            for rv in r[1]:
                for idx, k in enumerate(self._head[1:]):
                    self.line_out(d, col0_value=l[0], col_header=k,
                                  left_value='    ', right_value=rv[idx])
            return
        # print non matching
        for lv in l[1]:
            for rv in r[1]:
                for idx, k in enumerate(self._head[1:]):
                    if lv[idx] == rv[idx]:
                        continue  # same value
                    self.line_out(d, col0_value=l[0], col_header=k,
                                  left_value=lv[idx], right_value=rv[idx])

    def line_out(self, d, **kw):
        # manipulate and print output
        # the fields of the format string can be arbitrarily arranged
        # as long as the field names (between {} match)
        fmt = '{col0_header}#-{col0_value} : {col_header}-  ' \
            '{left_file_name} value = {left_value} / ' \
            '{right_file_name} value= {right_value}'
        d1 = d.copy()
        d1.update(kw)
        s = fmt.format(**d1)
        # s = s.rstrip()
        s = s[0].upper() + s[1:]  # sample output doesn't match input
        print(s)

    def get(self):
        item = self._buffer.popitem(last=False)
        self.fill_buffer()
        return item

    def fill_buffer(self):
        if self._fp is None:
            return
        while len(self._buffer) < self._max_diff:
            row = self._fp.readline().split(self._delim)
            if not row:
                self._fp.close()
                self._fp = None
                return
            entry = self._buffer.setdefault(row[0], [])
            entry.append(row[1:])

    def __contains__(self, key):
        self.fill_buffer()
        return key in self._buffer

rb1 = RowBuffer(sys.argv[1])
rb2 = RowBuffer(sys.argv[2])
rb1.compare(rb2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a (far from elegant) partial solution to your problem. It uses the first column as id column (it does not have to be the first one but you must definitely have one) and introduces a third dimension `suffix` to store multiple occurences of the same key. In the end it tries to find those keys of file 2 which have not been found in file 1.

```
BEGIN {
    IGNORECASE = 1
} 

NR==1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)    
        header[i] = $i
    suffix = 0
    previous_key=""
}

NR==FNR {
    if ($1 == previous_key) {
        suffix = suffix + 1
        max_suffix[$1] = suffix
    } else
        suffix = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        A[$1,suffix,i] = $i
    } 
    key_count[$1] = key_count[$1] + 1
    previous_key = $1
    next
}

{  
    if ($1 == previous_key)
        suffix = suffix + 1
    else
        suffix = 0
    previous_key = $1
    if (A[$1,suffix,1] != "") {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
            if (A[$1,suffix,i] != $i) {
                print header[1]"#-"$1": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", A[$1,suffix,i]" / " ARGV[2] " value= "$i
            }
        key_count[$1] = key_count[$1] - 1
    }
    else
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
            print header[1]"#-"$1": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", " / " ARGV[2] " value= "$i
}

END {
    for (missing_key in key_count) 
        if (key_count[missing_key] > 0) {            
            for (suffix = max_suffix[missing_key] - key_count[missing_key] + 1; suffix <= C[missing_key]; suffix++) 
                for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
                    print header[1]"#-"missing_key": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", A[missing_key,suffix,i] " / " ARGV[2] " value= "
        }           
}
```

There's a caveat: non-matching entries in file 2 are always printed at the end and not sorted according to the position in the file. Moreover the sorting of those lines is arbitrary. I guess this can be taken of by piping the result into a `sort` command.